# Why does ndcg_score result in nan values?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Consider the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, ndcg_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

X_data = sp.csr_matrix(X_data.to_numpy())
Y_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1,5], 100), columns=['Y'])

# Set the parameters by cross-validation
param_grid = {'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}

clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid, scoring=ndcg_score, refit=True, verbose=3, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
test = clf.fit(X_data, Y_data)
```

I am wondering why this would raise the following error:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 8 candidates, totalling 40 fits
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 431, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 285, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 222, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 625, in _fit_and_score
    test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, error_score)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 687, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 74, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 1564, in ndcg_score
    y_true = check_array(y_true, ensure_2d=False)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 710, in check_array
    array = array.astype(np.float64)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SVC'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-93a8890b095c> in <module>
     18 
     19 clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid, scoring=ndcg_score, refit=True, verbose=3, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
---> 20 test = clf.fit(X_data, Y_data)
     21 #print(test.best_score_)

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    839                 return results
    840 
--> 841             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    842 
    843             # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1294     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1295         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1296         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1297 
   1298 

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    793                               n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits))
    794 
--> 795                 out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),
    796                                                        X, y,
    797                                                        train=train, test=test,

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1052 
   1053             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1054                 self.retrieve()
   1055             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1056             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    931             try:
    932                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 933                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    934                 else:
    935                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541         try:
--> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544             raise TimeoutError from e

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    442                     raise CancelledError()
    443                 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 444                     return self.__get_result()
    445                 else:
    446                     raise TimeoutError()

~\Anaconda3\envs\kaggleSVM\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    387         if self._exception:
    388             try:
--> 389                 raise self._exception
    390             finally:
    391                 # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SVC'
```

I am not quite sure why this would result in a TypeError.

Comment: To debug, set `error_score="raise"`, so you can see the full error. I'm not too familiar with NDCG, but the docs suggest it's used with _multilabel_ problems, so maybe the format of your target is the problem.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for your comment. I received the following error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SVC'`. Unfortunately, I cannot wrap my head around it. There does not seem to be a SVC argument in: `gs = grid.fit(trainx[:,2:], trainy.ravel())`.

Comment: full error traceback, please.  And it looks like your new code is different from that in the question, so please reconcile those.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the code significantly, since this would allow other people to examine the problem without having a large data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot recreate the error you are reporting, but using `error_score="raise"` and `n_jobs=1` (not strictly necessary, but the output is a little easier to read), and wrapping `ndcg_score` with `make_scorer` with `needs_proba=True`, I get this one:

```
Only ('multilabel-indicator', 'continuous-multioutput', 'multiclass-multioutput') formats are supported. Got multiclass instead
```

which supports my first comment: NDCG assumes multilabel format.  That suggests you need to understand whether NDCG is really appropriate for your task, and if so either turn your problem into a multilabel one or write a custom scorer that converts the multiclass output into a multilabel (one-hot encoded) one before computing the score.